# rpc bind errors when disabling IPv6

Tags: ipv6, onc-rpc

I'm using the kernel command line parameter `ipv6.disable=1` in my boot loader (systemd boot) to disable IPv6. However, with that option, I now get these errors in the journal after booting up.

```
Jul 09 02:38:48 arch rpcbind[645]: cannot create socket for udp6
Jul 09 02:38:48 arch rpcbind[645]: cannot create socket for tcp6
Jul 09 02:38:48 arch rpc.statd[649]: Failed to create listener xprt (statd, 1, udp6)
Jul 09 02:38:48 arch rpc.mountd[642]: Could not make a socket: (97) Address family not supported by protocol
```

This is Arch Linux 4.14.53-1-lts #1 SMP Tue Jul 3 16:27:18 CEST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

What are the consequences of these errors and how do I resolve this while keeping IPv6 disabled?

More info: `rpcinfo -p`

```
program vers proto   port  service
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
100024    1   udp  48386  status
100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
100024    1   tcp  47193  status
100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100021    1   udp  54818  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  54818  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  54818  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  42833  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  42833  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  42833  nlockmgr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.snakeoil-os.net/forums/Thread-RESOLVED-rpcbind-cannot-create-socket-for-udp6-and-tcp6?page=2) is a solution that worked for me.

> This message is causing people to be confused that the problem is
>   caused by rpcbind when the problem is something else.
>
> For the benefit of google users, to disable this message, edit the
>   file /etc/netconfig, and disable these two lines (add a '#' character
>   at the beginning), such that they now read as thus:

```
#udp6       tpi_clts      v     inet6    udp     -       -
#tcp6       tpi_cots_ord  v     inet6    tcp     -       -
```

> Save the file, reboot the computer and you should no longer see the
>   "rpcbind: cannot create socket for udp6" messages.

As stated, it works and it seems to be the most correct solution. However, I do not fully understand all the nuances of this issue, so comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the bind ip manually.

man rpc.statd:

```
   -n, --name ipaddr | hostname
          Specifies  the  bind address used for RPC listener sockets.  The
          ipaddr form can be expressed as either an IPv4 or an  IPv6  pre‐
          sentation  address.   If this option is not specified, rpc.statd
          uses a wildcard address as the transport bind address.
```

Comment: How? Which config file or unit file?